# SQL Injection - is this query secure?

Tags: php, sql, security, sql-injection

I have a a page that appends different parameters to the URL that are used for the query.

For example

```
http://www.example.com/search.php?category=Schools&country[]=Belgium&country[]=Czech+Republic
```

My code is like this

```
if(isset($_GET['country'])){
$cties = "'" . implode("','", $_GET['country']) . "'";
}
else {
$cties = "'Albania','Andorra','Austria','Belarus','Belgium','Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina','Bulgaria','Croatia','Czech Republic','Denmark','Estonia','Faroe Islands','Finland','France','Germany','Gibraltar','Great Britain','Greece','Hungary','Iceland','Ireland','Isle of Man','Italy','Latvia','Liechtenstein','Lithuania','Luxembourg','Macedonia','Malta','Moldova','Monaco','Montenegro','Netherlands','Norway','Poland','Portugal','Serbia','Romania','San Marino','Slovakia','Slovenia','Spain','Sweden','Switzerland','Ukraine','United Kingdom'";           
}
if(isset($_GET['category'])){
$cat = $_GET['category'];
}
else{
$cat = " ";
}

try{
// create the Prepared Statement

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyDate >= DATE(NOW()) 
AND (Category=:cat or '' = :cat) 
AND Country IN ($cties)
ORDER BY MyDate ASC");
$stmt->bindValue(':cat', $cat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

I was wondering if this query is secure and if not, what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance!

I finally got it (thanks to Your Common Sense):

```
if(isset($_GET['country'])){
$arr = $_GET['country']; 
}
else {          
$arr = array('Albania','Andorra','Austria','Belarus','Belgium','Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina','Bulgaria','Croatia','Czech Republic','Denmark','Estonia','Faroe Islands','Finland','France','Germany','Gibraltar','Great Britain','Greece','Hungary','Iceland','Ireland','Isle of Man','Italy','Latvia','Liechtenstein','Lithuania','Luxembourg','Macedonia','Malta','Moldova','Monaco','Montenegro','Netherlands','Norway','Poland','Portugal','Serbia','Romania','San Marino','Slovakia','Slovenia','Spain','Sweden','Switzerland','Ukraine','United Kingdom');
}
if(isset($_GET['category'])){
$cat = $_GET['category'];
}
else{
$cat = " ";
}
// create the Prepared Statement
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyDate >= DATE(NOW()) 
    AND Country IN ($in)
    AND (Category=? or '' = ?) 
    ORDER BY MyDate ASC";
$stmt  = $con->prepare($sql);
$arr[] = $cat;  // adding category to array
$arr[] = $cat;  // we need it twice here
// finally - execute
$stmt->execute($arr);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15991146/285587

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thank you! Would you mind having a look at my edit? Does this fix the problem?

Comment: Nope. it rather makes no sense. You are supposed to add only **placeholders** in the query, but never actual data like you do.

Comment: Every time you add a raw variable you put yourself in danger. As simple as that. the only exception is if this variable contain hardcoded values only

Comment: @YourCommonSense Ok, I simply don't get it to work. I would be very grateful if you would guide me a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, Now I see your problem. Well, PDO is not too convenient a library for such a task. So, first of all I'll show you how it can be done with my own library:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyDate >= CURDATE() 
          AND (Category=?s or '' = ?s) 
          AND Country IN (?a)
          ORDER BY MyDate ASC"
$data = $db->getAll($sql, $cat, $cat, $_GET['country']);
```

But I quite realize that you all so inclined to familiar methods. Well, let's elaborate with ugly PDO

First of all, what is the goal? The goal is

1. **to create the query that contains placeholders for all the data.** I'll stick to positional placeholders as they are easier to implement.
2. To create an array with all the variables that have to be bound to placeholders

It seems we need two placeholders for category and some unknown number fro cities. All right, this line will create a string of placeholders:

```
$in   = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
```

which we are going to insert into query.

```
// $arr is array with all the vars to bind. at the moment it contains cities only
$arr = $_GET['country']; 
// creating string of ?s
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
// building query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyDate >= DATE(NOW()) 
              AND Country IN ($in)
              AND (Category=? or '' = ?) 
              ORDER BY MyDate ASC";
$stm  = $db->prepare($sql);
$arr[] = $_GET['category'];  // adding category to array
$arr[] = $_GET['category'];  // we need it twice here
// finally - execute
$stm->execute($arr);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I am getting closer. The only thing not working yet is when category is empty. But I'll fix that :-) Going to update my post as soon as the solution is found.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now. But can you explain me why I had to add category twice?

Comment: Because you have category twice in your qwuery

Answer (score 0):

No, the SQL code could be injected in the `$_GET['country']` parameter. You don't escape it anywhere.

See [PHP PDO: Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Comment: Thank you! Can you point me in the right direction on how to fix this?

Comment: Well, it made it worse.

Comment: Don't mix `mysqli_*` functions with PDO functions. Instead, use a prepared statement.

Comment: @Amal Murali There were, this post made a long way to look like this.

Comment: @AmalMurali [In history](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/e77b243e-0e93-42d0-81a0-14a2cf34d0f4/view-source).